# Show that the function $ f(z)= \begin{cases} \frac{\sin z}{z} , z \neq 0,\\ 1, z = 0. \end{cases}$ is analytic on the whole complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

To show this is true is it enough to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$. If so, why? Moreover, I am not quite sure how to calculate this limit. Should I use the identity that $\displaystyle\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$? Can you help me with these questions?

Comment: Look at the Taylor serie of the sinus.

Comment: @MisterDa for the limit?

Comment: yes, you will see that $\sin z \sim_{z\to0} z$ so $\frac{\sin z}{z} \sim_{z\to0} 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you are allowed to use but there is nothing to do if you know the serie expansion of the sine. You obtain directly 
$$
f(z) = \sum _{n=0}^{+\infty }{(-1)^{n}\frac {z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}}.
$$
With the d'Alembert ratio test, thanks to the factorial term in the denominator, the radius of convergence is $+\infty$. To see that, introduce $u_n = (-1)^{n}\frac {z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$, then $\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right| = \frac{|z|^2}{(2n+3)(2n+2)}$.

So it is an entire function (that is holomorphic/analytic on the whole complex plane).

Comment: Almost. You should still show that the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: Yes, i forgot that point. I edit my answer. Tanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I understand why limit is 1. I still wonder why this is sufficient to say that f is analytic at 1. For example, what would be the problem if, for example, $lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{sin z}{z} = 5$? Is it just continuity?

Comment: An holomorphic function is a (complex) differentiable (actually infinitely differentiable) function at every point $z_0$ of its domain. It means that $f(z_0+h) = f(z_0) + ah + o(h)$. You obtain $\lim_{h\to0} f(z_0+h) = f(z_0)$ which is the definition of continuity.